# Asynchronuos binding and LINQ query hangs

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq, user-interface, async-await

I have a **UI** control that takes `Enumerable` as its binding source. But until I set the binding source, I have to filter my original `Enumerable`. I would like to use **LINQ** for that purpose like that:

```
control.BindingSource = from var item in enumerable.Cast<ItemType>()
                        where item.X == 1
                        select item;
```

Here is a problem that UI hangs since enumerable is slow (e.g. if implemented like `yield return new Item(); Thread.Sleep(1000) ...`) and control attempts to execute query in UI thread. I've tried to solve this by using a combination of Task and async-await:

```
control.BindingSource = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                            (from var item in enumerable.Cast<ItemType>()
                             where item.X == 1
                             select item).ToArray());
```

Now UI doesn't hang, but results are visible at once after query execution completes. I solve this by using `ObservableCollection` and `Enumerator` with `await` beside `MoveNext` in `while` construct:

```
var source = new ObservableCollection<object>();
control.BindingSource = source;

var enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator();
while (await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => enumerator.MoveNext()))
{
    var item = (ItemType)enumerator.Current;

    if (item.X == 1)
        source.Add(item);
}
```

I'm looking for solution that will allow to use at least LINQ.
Have any ideas?

Comment: You should prefer `Task.Run` over `StartNew` in `async` code; [here's why](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `async` doesn't play very well with LINQ. There is an "asynchronous enumerator" that the Rx team experimented with, but I believe it has been abandoned.

The [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx) does have a standard approach for progress reporting, which you can use here.

```
private static void EvaluateItems(IEnumerable<ItemType> items, IProgress<ItemType> progress)
{
  if (progress == null)
    return;
  var query = from var item in items where item.X == 1 select item;
  foreach (var result in query)
    progress.Report(result);
}


var source = new ObservableCollection<object>();
control.BindingSource = source;
var progress = new Progress<ItemType>(item => source.Add(item));
await Task.Run(() => EvaluateItems(enumerable.Cast<ItemType>(), progress);
```

`IProgress`-based code has greater separation of concerns. The `EvaluateItems` method is only concerned with enumerating and filtering the items. It doesn't have to know that they're going into an `ObservableCollection` or that it's running in a WPF application (`Dispatcher`). So it's more portable and testable.

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
var query = from var item in enumerable.Cast<ItemType>()
            where item.X == 1
            select item;

var source = new ObservableCollection<object>();
control.BindingSource = source;

Task.Factory.StartNew(
    () =>
    {
        foreach(var item in query)
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                new Action(() => source.Add(item)));
        }
    },
    TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

Comment: Nice approach. I added `await` prior to task start in order to prevent method to continue till all items will be added and moved delegate creation outside the task due to avoid creating of new Action instance on each iteration.